# Contact form experiencing 30-second delay on submittal

Tags: php, forms, submit, delay

I'm updating a Contact Us form on a website. It seems like straightforward HTML and PHP, but I'm experiencing a 30-second delay from when I click the Submit button to when the mail() call finishes and the code displays the confirmation message on the page. The email sends successfully, and I get no error in the error log. The current contact form on our site does not experience this delay.

I tried testing some super-simple code and I'm having the same issue. I've been testing the files from a /test/2023contactform folder off the root folder, but I tried testing from the root folder, too, and have experienced the same delay.

Here's my super simple test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test email form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="contact" method="post" id="contact" action="test_email.php">
      <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
$to = "myemail@mydomain.com";
$subject = "My Subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: myemail@mydomain.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: myemail@mydomain.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
echo 'Thank You! Your message has been sent. We will contact you shortly.';
?>
```

If I comment out the mail() line, the echo message displays immediately upon clicking the submit button.

If I remove the parameters from the mail() line, the echo message displays immediately and I get an error log entry saying "mail() expects at least 3 parameters."

I parsed through the PHP for the site's current form and I don't see any special coding that I think would modify the response time.

My hosting service said that since the email went through and no errors were generated it isn't a problem with my code communicating with their server.

I'm at as loss as to what to try next. Any suggestions?

Comment: 30 seconds sounds a bit like a timeout to me, is everything configured correctly in the mail server side of things, and domain names and the like? I once had a POP3 server that stuck a 30s delay in when a certain client tried to connect because it was trying to do DNS lookup, couldn't, and waited for the timeout.

Comment: That does sound logical. I've not had to check mail server configurations before. Where would I go to do that?

Comment: The old contact page was created using bootstrap even through the rest of the site wasn't. I'm wondering if maybe that was done because there is some functionality within bootstrap that would configure the mail server or bypass the timeout. The original contact page calls mail.php. The mail.php file contains all the same html as the contact page as well as inline php for the form section. The form html in mail.php calls mail2.php `<form class="contact__form" method="post" action="mail2.php">` but there's no mail2.php file on our server.